# What is the maximum input voltage for the external voltage regulator of the stm32 bluepill?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, stm32, linear

I am referring to the regulator connected to the USB 5V ( the 5V pin), can it handle a voltage of 12v and step it down to 3.3V for the chip? If not, then what is the upper voltage limit for that regulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ones that use a Shanghai TX Electronics [TX6211B](http://txsemi.com/Upload/TX6211B_V13-10500396968.pdf) 3.3V regulator, the input range is 3.6V to 5.5V.

If you’re drawing external current from the 3.3V rail there may be thermal considerations.